# Performance while writing events into Cassandra table

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0

Query 1: Event data from device is stored in Cassandra table. Obviously this is time series data. If we need to store how older dated events (if cached in device due to some issue) at current time, are we going to get performance issue? If yes, what is the solution to avoid that?

Query 2: Is it good practice to write the event into Cassandra table as soon as the event comes in? Or shall we queue it for sometime to write multiple events in one go if that improves Cassandra write performance significantly?

Answer (score 1):

Q1: this all depends on the table design. Usually this shouldn't be an issue, but this may depend on your access patterns & compaction strategy.  If you have table structure, please share it.

Q2: Individual writes shouldn't be a problem, but it really depends on your requirements for throughput.  If you'll write several data points that **belong to the same partition key** you potentially may use unlogged batches, and in this case Cassandra will perform only one write for several inserts that are in this batch.  Please read [this document](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.1/cql/cql_using/useBatch.html).